# Fancybox inline not showing

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have the following:

in header:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function()
{

$(".modal").fancybox({ // for modals pages
        'autoSize' : true,
        'type' : 'ajax'
    }); 

$("#tip5").fancybox({
'scrolling'     : 'no',
'titleShow'     : false
});

$("#zoom").fancybox({ // for modal images
        'autoScale' : true,
        'transitionIn' : 'fade',
        'transitionOut' : 'fade'
    });


</script>
```

And then my html:

```
    <a href="#tip5" href="#login_form" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">Inline</a>

<div style="display:none">
    <form id="login_form" method="post" action="">
            <p id="login_error">Please, enter data</p>
        <p>
            <label for="login_name">Login: </label>
            <input type="text" id="login_name" name="login_name" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="login_pass">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" id="login_pass" name="login_pass" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <em>Leave empty so see resizing</em>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is just inline test code by the way to get it working first!

Anyway, simply nothing happens.

I use Fancybox elsewhere on my site for modal pages and images etc and thats all ok but inline not working??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, sorry, sorry people - my typing sucks! Double href was problem

```
 <a href="#tip5" href="#login_form"
```

should be

```
 <a id="tip5" href="#login_form"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting

```
href="#login-form" (with dash)
```

but your targeted form's ID is

```
<form id="login_form" ... (with underscore)
```

so the selector doesn't match. Silly, isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
<a href="#tip5" href="#login-form"...
```

vs.

```
<form id="login_form"...
```

the first is with a hypen (-) the second with an underscore (_)

Comment: Thanks, its not actually a typo on the correct code its my typing, i'll now copy and paste! Anyway, still not working